# What is the difference between ListView and SingleChildScrollView+ListBody in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, singlechildscrollview

I have a question about comparing `ListView` and `SingleChildScrollView` containing a `ListBody`. Seemingly, those two results look the same. But I'm curious about whether those two have a difference in function. In my opinion, it could be the part of efficiency or performance, but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance.

**SingleChildScrollView + ListBody**

```
final items = List.generate(100, (index) => index).toList();

SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ListBody(
    children: items.map((e) => Text('$e')).toList(),
  )
)
```

**ListView**

```
final items = List.generate(100, (index) => index).toList();

ListView(
  children: items.map((e) => Text('$e')).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I known one diff:

- ListView: is lazy load.
- ListBody is one-time loading.

Today , I fix a bug, Related to ListView lazy loading features
，I Change to ListBody , fix it .

I have a app, use flutter-markdown , i use ListView to render many markdown fragment，like this：

```
ListView(
   children: <Markdown>[..._contents], 
)
```

I use flutter_markdown.MarkdownElementBuilder to parse Markdown outline(TOC Table of Content), but flutter_markdown ast logic only run on Markdown.build(), so , If you don't pull down the ListView page to the bottom, you won't get the full outline ,bug show:
[bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLj2m.jpg)

I fixed this bug with ListBody

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ListBody(
       children: <Markdown>[..._contents], 
    )
)
```

after fix bug:
[bug fix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNAzf.jpg)

Additionally, if you are browsing a long page, there may be some stuck (Use ListView) when scrolling down ,   Because ListView loads calculations from time to time during pull-down.

- app ref: https://chen56.github.io/note/#/note/components/button
- bug ref:
  https://github.com/chen56/note/commit/c2510380407b20d93c9002ccbecdd8e23ed13a6d

Comment: I appreciate your answer and additional examples. I want to check my understanding of what you have said; in the case of ListView, the more extended height with many components, the more error could occur because of its lazy loading - is this correct?

Comment: Whoever sees this comment, please let me know whether it is true or not.

Comment: @chunzhi23 
> the more extended height with many components, the more error could occur because of its lazy loading 
no ,  my lazy loading

Comment: @chunzhi23 no, It's not a problem with ListView. The lazy loading mechanism of ListView is very good, but it's just due to the limitation of my usage scenario: I can't get the TOC of this markdown before the flutter_markdown loads all the content.I can only choose to give up not using ListView

Answer (score 0):

I must say I actually have never even heard of the widget `ListBody`, but when you check its source code you can actually see the comment:

```
/// This widget is rarely used directly. Instead, consider using [ListView],
/// which combines a similar layout algorithm with scrolling behavior, or
/// [Column], which gives you more flexible control over the layout of a
/// vertical set of boxes.
```

So the flutter devs themselves sort of don't recommend using it. I also don't know what the exact difference is, so I guess I'm not really answering your question. Maybe someone else can, but you also could just investigate the source code yourself, since it's all open source.